# How can I store an custom class as Data

Tags: swift, userdefaults

I want to use UserDefaults, and I think I cant store an Instance of a Struct that I coded by myself, am I right? Now is my question; How can I store an Custom Struct Instance as Data.
Thanks for your time
Boothosh

Comment: -> C o d a b l e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a custom object which conforms to `Codable`. A simple example:

```
struct MyObject: Codable {
    var something: String
}
```

And when you want to save it to UserDefaults, just `encode` it:

```
do {
    let encoded = try JSONEncoder().encode(MyObject(something: "String"))
    UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "kSavedObject")
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

If you want to retrieve it, you can use `decode`:

```
if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "kSavedObject") {
    do {
        let myRetrievedObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(MyObject.self, from: data)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: The asker asked about a CLASS not a STRUCT. This answer is inaccurate